# Multi-line text background with animation

Tags: css

What I'm looking to do is add a background color behind some text on hover, which I've already done here:

https://jsfiddle.net/95utp3g2/9/

Is there a way to animate the background color such that it appears from left to right, line by line? What I mean by that is that, on hover, the background should animate from left to right on the first line only. Then, a couple milliseconds later, the background should animate for the second line. Then a couple milliseconds later, the background should animate for the third line.

Is there a way to do this with CSS only?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, eiusmod tempor incididunt.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
}

.text {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.text:hover {
  background: gold;
  padding: 2px 0;
}
```

Comment: The one thing that came to mind was positioning, but I'm not sure how I would position specifically the background color.

Comment: You're gonna need javascript. You'd need a positioned span for each line of text and animate it into place...one after the other...pure CSS would be possible but it would be a shipload of code. JS would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could come up with<strike>, which still required some 1x1px images (since apparently linear-gradients can't be animated yet),</strike> was to make sure each line was specifically sized (from your existing CSS it seemed like that was OK), then use multiple backgrounds with specific sizes and animate their background-positions with some @keyframe animations.  The relevant CSS I added:

```
.text {
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(red, red), linear-gradient(green, green), linear-gradient(red, red);
  background-size: 250px 26px, 250px 26px, 250px 26px;
  background-position: -250px 0, -250px 26px, -250px 52px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
}    

.text:hover {
  animation: myanim 2s;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 26px, 0 52px;
}

@keyframes myanim {
  0% {
    background-position: -250px 0, -250px 26px, -250px 52px;
  } 
  33% {
    background-position: 0 0, -250px 26px, -250px 52px;
  }
  67% {
    background-position: 0 0, 0 26px, -250px 52px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0, 0 26px, 0 52px;
  }
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbxw5sw0/)**

Comment: Doh, I stand corrected. Thank you! I must have been getting the syntax wrong, then the issue "confirmed" with outdated S.O. answers. I've updated the answer.